# Why do I keep getting 4 slides when there are only 3 div elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a slideshow with 3 slides but for some reason, it keeps adding an additional slide

```js
const slideshow = document.getElementById("slideshow");
const slides = slideshow.children;
let currentSlide = 0;

function goToSlide(n) {
  slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("active");
  currentSlide = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].classList.add("active");
  updateSlideshowCounter();
}

function nextSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}

function prevSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide - 1);
}

function updateSlideshowCounter() {
  const slideshowCounter = document.getElementById("slideshow-counter");
  slideshowCounter.textContent = `${currentSlide + 1} / ${slides.length}`;
}

const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev-button");
prevButton.addEventListener("click", prevSlide);

const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
nextButton.addEventListener("click", nextSlide);

updateSlideshowCounter();
```

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

#slideshow-controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#prev-button,
#next-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prev-button {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#next-button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#slideshow-counter {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
  <div id="slideshow-controls">
    <button id="prev-button">Prev</button>
    <span id="slideshow-counter"></span>
    <button id="next-button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what my mistake is and how I can get 3 slides in the output instead of 4.

Comment: Because `.slideShow` has four children: 3 x `.slide` and 1 x `.slideshow-controls`.

Comment: Replace `const slides = slideshow.children;` with `const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");`

Comment: And I forgot , gotta love the speed of SO people...

Comment: The following will display 1/3,  <div id="slideshow"> ... </div>, close the slideshow div before the slideshow-controls DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining your slides with the statement `const slides = slideshow.children;`. Your slideshow has a total of 4 direct children, so the counter is technically correct (see slide 1, slide 2, slide 3, and slideshow-controls).

One approach to get just the slides you want is to use `const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide")`. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your slides variable is not assigned to the correct list of elements, as the previous answer said, you should replace `slideshow.children` with either `document.getElementsByClassName('slide')` or `document.querySelectorAll('.slide')`, use any of the two.

By using `slideshow.children`, you're not getting `.slide` classes, you're getting all children of `#slideshow`.

So, your variable in line 67, should be as the following:

```js
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
```

or

```js
const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('.slide');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep slideshow controls out of your slideshow div. I am attaching Code Below. Run it and check.

```js
const slideshow = document.getElementById("slideshow");
const slides = slideshow.children;
let currentSlide = 0;

function goToSlide(n) {
  slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("active");
  currentSlide = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].classList.add("active");
  updateSlideshowCounter();
}

function nextSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}

function prevSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide - 1);
}

function updateSlideshowCounter() {
  const slideshowCounter = document.getElementById("slideshow-counter");
  slideshowCounter.textContent = `${currentSlide + 1} / ${slides.length}`;
}

const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev-button");
prevButton.addEventListener("click", prevSlide);

const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
nextButton.addEventListener("click", nextSlide);

updateSlideshowCounter();
```

```css
#slideshowbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

#slideshow-controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#prev-button,
#next-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prev-button {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#next-button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#slideshow-counter {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshowbox">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="slideshow-controls">
    <button id="prev-button">Prev</button>
    <span id="slideshow-counter"></span>
    <button id="next-button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your slideshow div childs is throwing 4 because your 4th div is slideshow-controls. You may want to add -1 to the counter or redifine the way you make your div. Best of luck!